# Why I ain't able to open a file after downloading "virtualenv env" as I saw it in a Yt tutorial video

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I decided to learn the Django tutorial from the Yt video but as I saw that guy gave a command "pip install "virtulenv env" and a new file was opened in his file explorer. Then he again downloaded several other stuffs but I stucked on this step only and he moved ahead of me completing Django download successfully and started coding.

But the issue is when that guy typed "virtualenv env" after installing the Virtual Environment, a file named "env" opened. This is the issue that I'm not achieving through doing as same he did.Why?

A complete set up guidance for Django environment for Windows11, including commands and if raised any issue their solutions.

Comment: what's your actual question?

Comment: Are you sure that's *exactly* the command they put in? Or did they *say* "pip install virtual env" and really put in something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe make sure that you have the `venv` package installed.
You can type the following line in order to do that:

```
python3 -m venv
```

Or:

```
py -m venv
```

If the `venv` package can't be found, try installing it again.

With venv installed, type the following line:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Or:

```
py -m venv env
```

Note: you may need to **cd** into the folder afterwards using:

```
cd env
```